# Draggable event with owl carousel and Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have some problem with Owl carousel mixed with Jquery UI.

Carousel is used to show slides with various content (Html forms and images uploader.)

One of slides contain uploader, which dynamicly upload user images, and show thumbnails of this images.

One of problems was, that this content is dynamic, and after upload, slide don't change height, so user can't see this thumbnails.

But i done this using:

```
setInterval(function(){
                $(".owl-carousel").each(function(){
                    $(this).data('owlCarousel').updateVars();
                });
            },3000)
```

So every 3 seconds script update height.

But now, i heve problem: User may have option to drag this thumbnails, so he can change order of images, to show on gallery. i have used for this purpose Jquery UI and draggable effect.

But this will not work, because Owl carousel don't allow to drag items. My code is very simple, i have generic function for owl carousel:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true,
        autoHeight:true,

});
```

And for li ement, inside slide (which holds thumbnails):

```
$( "li" ).draggable({
});
```

Now, code above will allow to drag any `<li>` element, outside of owl carousel, but not my thumbnails.

Html code is very simple just for needs of this question:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">

<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
</div>

<div class="item thumbs">
<ul>
  <li>here i have thumbnail</li>
</ul>
```

I need to note, that it may help me, if i can disable owl carousel swipe effect, and only allow to change slide, by using navigation (attachment) - it also may be good, because thumbnails dragging is most important....
(red area may be disabled, so no left / right swiping, slides changes only by green buttons, and images draggable.)

Thanks for advice.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can set mouseDrag:false. to owl-carousel. It will disable the self dragging and enable the native one.